# How load data only with a ng-model in a column

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have a treeGrid load data with template in directive angularjs.
I will fill custom a column and fill it with simple directive in another js file.
For example: FirstName,LastName column filled with directive1 in app1.js
and Age column will fill with directive2 in app2.js.
How i do it ?

```
  module.directive('treeGrid', [
  '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          //templateUrl:'tree-grid-template.html',
          template: "<div class=...
      }
     ])
```

Comment: can you please create a plunkr link with your code

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/BAUsZ0Zq4dgKVwJ3wWHJ?p=preview